# Converting Rows containing Years into Columns

Tags: excel, ms-access, sas

In order to input data into SAS it is required to be in the following format:

```
Country Year Indicator_1
Belgium 1900 x1
Belgium 1901 x2
...
Belarus 1901 x1
```

However, most of my data comes in the following format:

```
Country 1900 1901 1902 ... etc
Belgium x1____x2___x3  ...etc
Belarus x1____x2___x3  ...etc
```

Is there an easy Macro or VBA script that can help?

Comment: Can you use awk or something similar? is easier that way!

Answer (score 3):

### parse apart the indicator string into year variables

assuming there will be more than 3 years worth of data, you'd need to adjust the format and array referencing Y1900-Y1902.

```
data original;
    infile datalines;
    format Country $20. YearIndicator $50.;
    input Country YearIndicator;

    format Y1900-Y1902 $4.;
    array y(*) y1900-y1902;
    do i = 1 to dim(y);
        y[i] = scan(YearIndicator,i,'_');
    end;
    drop i;
datalines;
Belgium x1____x2___x3
Belarus x1____x2___x3
run;
```

### make wide table tall

```
proc transpose data=original out=talldata(rename=(_NAME_=CYear COL1=Indicator));
    by country notsorted;
    var y1900-y1902;
run;
```

### make year variable numeric, not character

```
data talldata;
    format Country $20. Year 4. Indicator $4.;
    set talldata;
    year=input(compress(cyear,,'kd'),4.);
    drop cyear;
run;
```

### view results

```
proc print data=talldata; run;
```

### output

```
Obs    Country                 Year    Indicator

 1     Belgium                 1900      x1
 2     Belgium                 1901      x2
 3     Belgium                 1902      x3
 4     Belarus                 1900      x1
 5     Belarus                 1901      x2
 6     Belarus                 1902      x3
```

Comment: Just curious: What does the 'kd' in compres() do?

Comment: in the `compress` function, `kd` as the third argument tells sas to k(eep) d(igits).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Union query:

```
SELECT Country, 1900 As SYear, [1900] As Indicator FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 1901 As SYear, [1901] As Indicator FROM Table

<..>

UNION ALL
SELECT Country, 2010 As SYear, [2010] As Indicator FROM Table
```

You can use this to create a table if it is not possible to export a query.

Answer (score 0):

If the input raw data are regular enough then this can be done very easily with a simple data step as below.

```
   data one;
     infile cards dlm=" _" missover;
     input country :$20. @;
     do year = 1900 to 1902;
       input indicator $ @;
       output;
     end;
   cards;
   Belgium x1____x2___x3
   Belarus x4____x5___x6
   ;
   run;

   /* check */
   proc print data=one;
   run;
   /* on lst
   Obs    country    year    indicator
    1     Belgium    1900       x1
    2     Belgium    1901       x2
    3     Belgium    1902       x3
    4     Belarus    1900       x4
    5     Belarus    1901       x5
    6     Belarus    1902       x6
   */
```